Picker tags ignoring set ID and using index instead
I have the following Picker:
Picker("Film", selection: $fields.filmId) {
    ForEach(config.films.filter { $0.active }, id: \.id) { film in
        Text(film.stock).tag(film.id)
    }
}

ID is simply a unique Int that I set on each one, there are only about 12 entries in config.films.filter. I have a subview that uses a Picker and Toggle to allow me to hide values from the main picker:
ForEach(config.films, id: \.self) { film in
    if let index = config.films.firstIndex(of: film) {
        Toggle(isOn: $config.films[index].active) {
            Text(film.stock)
        }
    }
}

This sub picker doesn't do anything but set .active to true or false on each one. It does hide them but the issue is that when I go back to the main view, it will select a value that is proportional to how many I hid on the subview.
For example, say the main picker has 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and I select 3. If I hide 1, 2 on the sub view, when I go back the selected value will be 5. However, if I hide 4, 5, the main picker will keep 3 selected. It's only when I hide values that come before the selected does it break leading me to believe it's the index.
Any ideas why this is? I thought .tag would allow the Picker to reference it's items by the tag but it seems it's going by index of the items still.

Minimal code to reproduce issue
If you run the following and select Three on the picker then click the checkbox next to One or Two, you'll see the picker gets set to Four or Five. If the value exists in the picker, it should remain selected.
import SwiftUI

struct Film: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    var active = true
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var films: [Film]
    @State var filmId: Int
    
    init () {
        let films = [
            Film(id: 0, name: "One"),
            Film(id: 1, name: "Two"),
            Film(id: 2, name: "Three"),
            Film(id: 3, name: "Four"),
            Film(id: 4, name: "Five")
        ]
        
        _films = State(initialValue: films)
        _filmId = State(initialValue: 2)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Picker("Film", selection: $filmId) {
                ForEach(films.filter { $0.active }, id: \.id) { film in
                    Text("\(film.name)").tag(film.id)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: films) {
                print(films)
                
            }
            
            List {
                ForEach($films, id: \.id) { film in
                    if let index = films.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == film.id }) {
                        Toggle(isOn: $films[index].active) {
                            Text(films[index].name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


Since film has an id, have you tried ForEach(config.films.filter { $0.active }) { ...}. In any case you should not use id: \.self.

@workingdogsupportUkraine That was a typo on my end, the main picker uses \.id not \.self. The second Picker shouldn't matter, it just gives me a list to activate or not on the main one. Other than that there is no relation.

Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code.
Enough code that we can compile and run to reproduce your problem. In particular what is fields.filmId and config and its films and how you declare these
in the view and pass it to the subview.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Please see updated question, I added a full code snippet you can copy to reproduce.

Your example code works fine for me when running on an iPhone 16 simulator with iOS 18.0. It starts off with 3 selected, if 1 and 2 are turned off, 3 stays selected.

Yes, I get that too, but if you turn off 3, then you get ..is invalid and does not have an associated tag, this will give undefined results.

Looks like everyone is trying to reproduce this at the same time:) I failed to reproduce as well both on macOS and iOS. I guess it could be related to how the real data source is defined.

@JoakimDanielson Try it on watchOS.

@BenzyNeez Try on watchOS, that’s what I’m using.

I could reproduce on watchOS but I haven't been able to find a solution.
